# Markers in document for custom TOC

Tags: table-of-contents, pdf, metadata, page

What I would like to do is place `markers` with custom keys into my document to generate a TOC from. I imagine this to look something like the following:

```
\Section{A}
Lorem impsum
\marker{foo}
Neque porro

\Section{B}
Quisquam est qui\marker{bar}
```

Using these markers I would like to create a page listing all markers together with the corresponding page numbers like so

```
foo......p.1
bar......p.2
```

Is there any way / command to achieve a similar behavior in latex? Alternatively I would also be happy if there was some postprocessing command with which I could extract the position of these markers in the final pdf without actually listing/seeing them.

Comment: you can try with [etoc](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/etoc) package.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a suggestion using package `tocbasic`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tocbasic}
\DeclareNewTOC[
  owner=\jobname,
  type=marker,
  listname={List of Markers},
  tocentrylevel=1,
  tocentrystyle=tocline,
  tocentryindent=0pt,
  tocentrynumwidth=0pt
]{mrk}
\newcommand\marker[1]{%
  \addxcontentsline{mrk}{marker}{#1}%
}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\listofmarkers
\section{A}
Lorem impsum
\marker{foo}%
Neque porro
\lipsum[1-10]
\section{B}
Quisquam est qui\marker{bar}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]